# What can cause the request body to become empty in node.js express?

Tags: node.js, nginx

For some reason the body in our post requests is made empty.
The browser is sending the data, we can see that the body is present in our NGINX server, but once it arrives at the node.js server is appears to be missing.

I have used 'util' to print out the entire request, which is huge, so I thought I would list the "body-related" attributes below

```
parser:
.....      
onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
    ....
 _httpMessage:
  ....
    _hasBody: true,

....

body: {},
```

all other data seems to be there, cookies etc...
the request object also contains all routing information.
Could the "parserOnBody" be the cause ?

It is not occurring for all routes, the POST requests for other routes do contain a body.

node.js is running in container, the nginx server is running on the host-os, could there be an issue with the request forwarding ?

Below a the start of our method

```
// add answer
app.post('/questions/:id([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/answers'
, passport.authenticate('token', { session: false })
, fetch(models.Question)
, stream()
, function(req, res) {
//console.log('add answer req '+util.inspect(req, false, null));
var question = req.model;

var answer = req.body;
console.log('add answer body '+util.inspect(answer, false, null));
```

The commented line prints the huge request, the second log entry prints {}.
I know console.log should be avoided, but I need a way to transport my findings...

Comment: How are you retrieving the body from the request?

Comment: Are you sending `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @KevinB I have update the question with code...

Comment: @KevinB you are fast ! now I have

Comment: and, what is `req`? is it coming from express? node.js http?

Comment: Do you have any middleware in place that will parse the body for you? (usually called *bodyparser*)

Comment: Yeah, what's `stream()`?

Comment: @robertklep it is an AJAX call where we post JSON

Comment: @KevinB do you mean entries like this ?
  , fetch = require('../middleware/fetch')
  , async = require('async')
  , stream = require('../middleware/stream')
  , auth = require('../middleware/authorize')

Comment: Yes, it would look something like this if you had it: `app.use(bodyparser.json())` https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser note that body-parser wont' handle multi-part bodies, but it's readme does provide a few alternatives.

Comment: @robertklep stream() is a function to identify the "stream" where the questions and answers belong to. This is also the same across working and non-working functions. Posting a question works, posting an answer does not ...

Comment: @KevinB yes, I have it like this: app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true })); Adding limit does not make a difference. Since we are posting JSON using AJAX, I think this shoud work (and it does work in other places). So basically I am looking for a entry point to start troubleshooting. Can I see/inspect what the bodyParser does ?

Comment: you must be using an older version of express, bodyParser doesn't come with it anymore.

Comment: @KevinB that might very well be the case, this is an "inheritance" from more than 18 months ago.

Comment: Basically, if the request has proper content-type header, and the bodyparser middleware is setup to properly parse that content type, you should be able to access the data in req.body, or as a parameter, depending on the type of data.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB I''ll take a closer look at the bodyparser middleware and report back here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the parseBody middleware I found that the contentlength of the request is **0**. The parser concludes: *no body*, which seems correct.

I added a debug log format for the NGINX server

```
log_format  debug  '[$time_local] "$request" '
                  ' "#$http_transfer_encoding" [$http_content_length] '
                 '"$request_length"  [$request_body_file]';
```

When we replay the error scenario, we see two requests coming in, the first one gives an content_length of zero, which explains the empty body in our node.js server. The second one does not arrive...

```
[18/Jun/2015:13:18:31 +0200] "POST /api/questions/558138bdde3afb400400001d/answers HTTP/1.1"  "#-" [0] "890"  [-]
[18/Jun/2015:13:18:31 +0200] "POST /api/questions/558138bdde3afb400400001d/answers HTTP/1.1"  "#-" [1623] "2383"  [-]
```

The second line correponds with the line we get when we have a succesful request.

The issue remains, but it is no longer a node.js express issue. Hence this answer.